# Beamer footnote disappears with luatexja package

Tags: beamer, luatexja

I found an interesting behavior of `luatexja` package. Compiling the following code by `lualatex`, the footnote disappears.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{luatexja} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sample}
  Footnote disappears\footnote{You can not see this.}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When I comment out the second line `\usepackage{luatexja}`, the footnote is shown.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\let\orig@@footnotetext\@footnotetext
\usepackage{luatexja}
\let\@footnotetext\orig@@footnotetext
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sample}
    Test\footnote{Footnote test.}.
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This time footnote does not disappear. It seems that `\@footnotetext` is overwritten by lltjcore.sty. (Reported to [the ticket forum](https://osdn.jp/ticket/browse.php?group_id=5593&tid=36262).)